# Ext JS 4: Reusing radiogroup class in Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to reuse a radiogroup class that I've created, but I can't seem to get it working.  Here's my code:

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
  name: 'Test',
  appFolder: 'app',
  controllers: ['RadioController'],
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
      layout: 'border',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        title: 'buttons',
        items: [{
          xtype: 'form',
          items: [{
            xtype: 'radiobuttons',
            fieldLabel: 'group 1',
            //name: '1',
            defaults: {
              name: 'button1'
            }
          }, {
            xtype: 'radiobuttons',
            fieldLabel: 'group 2',
            //name: '2',
            defaults: {
              name: 'button2'
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

**RadioController.js**

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.RadioController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  models: [],
  stores: [],
  views: ['RadioButtons'],
  init: function() {
  }
});
```

**RadioButtons.js**

```
Ext.define('Test.view.RadioButtons', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.RadioGroup',
  alias: 'widget.radiobuttons',
  items: [{
    boxLabel: 'radio 1',
    inputValue: 'radio 1'
  }, {
    boxLabel: 'radio 2',
    inputValue: 'radio 2'
  }]
});
```

What happens is, the page gets loaded, and everything looks right.  However, when I click a radio button in 'group 1' and then click a radio button in 'group 2', I lose the clicked button in 'group 1'.  I thought radio buttons worked off of the 'name' property, and if they had a different name property, they'd basically be in a different group... thus, I shouldn't lose group 1's clicked button.  Basically, I'm trying to create [this jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/JbUk8/3/) by reusing a class I've made.  Is this possible?

It's good to note that if I use the class's code in place of using the class, I can get my results, but this isn't good practice because that's what classes try to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me... thanks to bizcasfri on the Sencha forums.

**RadioButtons.js**

```
Ext.define('RadioButtons', {
  extend : 'Ext.form.RadioGroup',
  alias  : 'widget.radiobuttons',
  constructor: function (config) {
    Ext.apply(this, {
      defaults: {
        xtype: 'radio',
        name: config.name
      },
      items: [
        {
          boxLabel: 'Radio 1',
          inputValue: '1'
        },
        {
          boxLabel: 'Radio 2',
          inputValue: '2'
        }
      ]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
  name: 'Test',
  appFolder: 'app',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
      layout: 'border',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        title: 'buttons',
        items: [{
          xtype: 'form',
          items: [{
            xtype: 'radiobuttons',
            fieldLabel: 'group 1',
            name: 'radiogroup1'
          }, {
            xtype: 'radiobuttons',
            fieldLabel: 'group 2',
            name: 'radiogroup2'
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

Take note of the constructor method in the RadioButtons class... that's the trick to it all!